# Rails How to show attributes from a parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have 2 tables - user.rb and profile.rb.

```
User has one profile
Profile belongs to User
```

User has string attributes called :first_name and :last_name

In my profile show view, I have this line:

```
<%= "#{@profile.user.first_name} #{@profile.user.last_name}" %>
```

I'm now trying to make a profile index view page, with this element:

```
 <% Profile.all.sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
      <div class="row">
        <% group.compact.each do |profile| %>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="indexdisplay">
              <%= image_tag profile.image_url, width: '100%', height: '200px' if profile.image.present? %>
                  <div class="indexheading"> <%= link_to "#{@profile.user.first_name} #{@profile.user.last_name}" %>, profile %> </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
              <% end %>
              </div>

    <% end %>
```

I get an error, which says:

```
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand how the line works properly in the show view, but does not work in the index view. I also don't understand why it thinks user is a method. it's a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling method `user` on `@profile`. Yes, it is an associated record, but it is a method call. The issue is you are calling it on an instance variable `@profile`, which given the information provided does not exist. Instance variables which don't exist when called return a `nil`. Calling a method on `nil` results in the error message you are experiencing.

The parent looping wrapper of `<%= "#{@profile.user.first_name} #{@profile.user.last_name}" %>` is an each loop of `profile` in `group`. Replace the instance variable `@profile` with variable `profile`. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

> undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

To give you more context, this error means **your variable has not been populated with data**.

I write this because it's an issue most new Ruby developers don't realize - this is not an error with a "method" for a variable, but the variable being non-existent itself.

Because Ruby is *object orientated*, it will assign the variable to the `NilClass` in order to populate it. Thus, instead of saying the variable doesn't exist, it will say that you're calling an undefined method on a variable with no data.

To fix it, you have to make sure you've populated your variable properly.

---

**Fixes**

> I'm now trying to make a profile index view page

Populate your data in your *controller*, not your view:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @profiles = Profile.all.order :created_at
   end
end

#app/views/profiles/index.html.erb
<% @profiles.in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

--

This is your problem.

You're calling `@profile` when it doesn't exist.

Do this instead:

```
#app/views/profiles/index.html.erb
<% @profiles.in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
   <% group.each do |profile| %>
      <%= link_to "#{profile.user.first_name} #{profile.user.last_name}" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```