# Rails Carrierwave Imagemagik - specifying sizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I am trying to use Rails 4 to make an app. I use carrierwave with 'mini_magick' to handle images.

I created a file called: avatar_uploader.rb, which has the following content:

```
  process :resize_to_fit => [800, 800]
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
    end

    version :profile do
        process :resize_to_fill => [345,245]
    end


    version :wider do
      process :resize_to_fill => [951,245]
    end

    version :small do
          process :resize_to_fill => [35,35]
    end
```

The version called :small was originally called :logo. However, some of the models I want to use it on had attributes called: logo and so when I wanted to use the version, I had .logo.logo in the line.

However, I posted this question and the answer (under the heading Trivia - point 2) advised not to use the same word twice in a row. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916133/rails-how-to-show-attribute-of-an-associated-model`

That's why I changed the name of the version in the avatar_uploader.rb to small.

However, now when I try to render the show page: as

```
<%= link_to university_path(@profile.university) do %>

        <%= image_tag(@profile.university.try(:logo).small) %>

        <%= @profile.university.name %>
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /profiles/3
undefined method `small' for nil:NilClass
```

The name displays correctly and the image displays as a box with a question mark in it. I use the same image in other parts of the code with different version sizes and it works correctly.

Is there something that needs to be done to refresh the avatar uploader content?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling for the picture in the show page?  Did you add `mount_uploader` to the model?

Comment: What is the name of the picture attribute in your model?

Comment: In the universities table, I have an attribute called :logo

Answer (score 0):

In your university.rb file you should have have the line `mount_uploader :logo, AvatarUploader`.

You should have an attribute called logo which is a string in your model.

I am assuming the model is called universities.  Then in your image tag all you need to do is `image_tag @profile.university.logo.small.url`.

Comment: I already had mounted the uploader. I tried removing the brackets and the 'try' & adding '.url' as you suggested - it doesnt work - i get the same error

Comment: Are you able to get the picture by making an instance of a university and then calling @university.logo.small.url?  Can you post more of your code?