# Rails: showing an attribute from an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have a profile show page which should include the name of the university that the profile belongs to.

I have this link in my profiles#show:

```
<%= link_to @profile.university.name do %>
            <span class="profiletitle"> <%= @profile.university.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

I have a profile model and a university model. The associations are:

```
profile: belongs_to :university

university: has_many :profiles
```

In my universities table, I have an attribute called :name.

When I try this, I get an error saying:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /profiles/University%20of%20Melbourne
Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=University of Melbourne
```

It refers to my profiles controller, which has (at the line where the error reference points):

```
 def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
 end
```

I dont understand why this reference is relevant or how to reference the university name from the profile show. I want ti to works so you click the link and it takes you to the uni overview show page.

How do you reference an attribute from an associated model?

I have asked several other questions trying to fix this error. The most recent one is here. There is an extensive answer given, but I don't want the associations set out like the suggestion provides for so I"m getting lost on how to follow along with the content of the answer.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916133/rails-how-to-show-attribute-of-an-associated-model
```

Thank you

When I take Prashant's suggestion and try:

```
<%= link_to universities_path(@profile.university) do %>
   <span class="profiletitle"> <%= @profile.university.name %></span>
 <% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

It references this action in my universities controller:

```
def index
    @universities = University.all
    respond_with(@university)
  end
```

My profile routes are:

```
resources :profiles do
    resources :account_histories
  end
```

Comment: please post your routes for profiles

Comment: look like routes mistakenly taking name for id

Comment: i added my profile routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yourUse like this:

**UPDATE**

```
 <%= link_to university_path(@profile.university) do %>
   <span class="profiletitle"> <%= @profile.university.name %></span>
 <% end %>
```

Your routes.rb should contain this

```
resources :universities do
  resources :profiles
  # other stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Prashant, I tried this and copied my error message above

Comment: Thanks, that works except the span styling doesn't apply to the label (being the name of the university - is it in the wrong spot??)