# Rails - counting instances where boolean is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have a project model and a project invitations model.

```
Projects has many project invitations
Project invitations belong to projects
```

In my project show, Im trying to count how many invitations have been sent and how many have been accepted.

The first part works fine. For the acceptances, I have an attribute in my project_invitation table called :student_accepted. If that is true, I want to count the record.

```
<%= @project.project_invitations.size %>
            <% if @project.project_invitations.student_accepted == true %>
                <%= @project.project_invitations.size %>
                <% else %>
                'No'
            <% end %>
```

It gives this error:

```
undefined method `student_accepted' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I have also tried:

```
<% if project.project_invitations.student_accepted == true %>

<%= project.project_invitations.size %>
```

It gives this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `project' for #<#<Class:0x007fc01d9dcbe8>:0x007fc01de04248>
```

Im struggling to understand how to reference attributes though associated models. I have read several books but they all assume background knowledge. I've had helpful input on related questions (below), but still not grasping the concept.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916133/rails-how-to-show-attribute-of-an-associated-model

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898541/rails-how-to-show-attributes-from-a-parent-object
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the number of invitations that students have accepted with:

```
@project.project_invitations.where(student_accepted: true).count
```

Rails's [Active Record Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) explains how that works.

The reason you received the `undefined method 'student_accepted' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` error is because you were calling `student_accepted` on a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, which is an object rails creates to define a collection of records.

If you wanted to iterate over that collection you could do:

```
<% @project.project_invitations.each do |invitation| %>
  # here you can call `invitation.student_accepted`
<% end %>
```

This is necessary because a project *has many* invitations.

Answer (score 1):

`@project.project_invitations` gives you an array and Array class does not have the method `student_accepted` (while each item in the array has this method).

You can use `@project.project_invitations.select{|item| item.student_accepted == true}.present?` as the condition.

Comment: Technically, it returns an instance of [ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy), hence the error message.  In many cases it can be treated as an array, and it can be converted to an array with `to_a`, but it is not an `Array` object.

Comment: Right. While `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` share some methods names with `Array`, they are not the same.